# How can I post a comment on a YouTube video? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to post a comment on a YouTube video programmatically using `google-api-nodejs-client`. Any ideas how can I do so?

I would really appreciate if a code sample is provided.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to do it!

Here's the code in case anyone is looking for an answer.

```js
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET", []),
    google = require('googleapis'),
    ytdapi = google.youtube('v3');

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: "REFRESH_TOKEN"
});

var params = {
    auth: oauth2Client,
    part: "snippet",
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        channelId: "CHANNEL_ID",
        videoId: "VIDEO_ID",
      topLevelComment: {
        snippet: {
          textOriginal: "YOUR TEXT HERE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


ytdapi.commentThreads.insert(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send("Error posting comment ");
  }
  else {
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).send("Successfully posted comment ");
  }
});
```

Comment: what is "ytdapi" here?

Comment: @GopinathShiva I've updated the sample to include the variable declaration. let me know if you need more help.